# Getting argument lists from ARM dynamic libraries (frameworks)?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, frameworks, arm

I have a number of private frameworks I want to use, however I cannot find any headers for them. Is there a de-facto way of getting arguments from **C** function calls using **IDA Pro**? (Not `ObjC` messages).

Edit: Oops, I meant **C** not *C++*.

Comment: What does this have to do with Core Foundation?

Comment: Good point, I don't know why I was thinking of Core Foundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access r0-r3 and the stack pointer?

Answer (score 1):

In C, there's no way, other than just looking at the assembly code and extracting the parameters manually.